# Anyone got a SIMPLE example of how to read a MIDI file with Haskell

Tags: haskell, midi

Trying to learn Haskell, done some of the basic examples from the well known books but would like to try something more relevant. Found the midi and the Haskore libraries but I can't figure out the basics.

I'd love to see a really simple example of how to load a MIDI file (preferably a format 1 file) and access events in the various tracks.

Comment: The haskell midi package has a function which will read a midi: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/midi-0.2.1.1/docs/Sound-MIDI-File-Load.html. Just call the function on the file path and you've read the file. I imagine you want to do more than just read the file but I know nothing about midi, you should be more specific about what exactly you want to do with the data once it has been read from a file.

Comment: I asked for example code (not for a library nor off-site resource, etc) for how to read a MIDI file in a particular language (Haskell) --- how is that off-topic or an opportunity for spam?

Comment: I know lots about MIDI ---- I just don't know too much about Haskell other than the basics. I'm assuming that once I have access to a sequence I'll be able to figure out "the haskell way" to manipulate the events. I had installed that midi package already but I'm still not expert enough to figure out how to use some of these things from the basic docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend [The Haskell School of Music -- From Signals to Symphonies](http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/?post_type=publication&p=112) by Paul Hudak

Comment: Excellent --- I've pulled it down --- in the meantime, I'd still like a simple example (hello world style) of a complete program that can read a MIDI file from disk